# Where is MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() in ASP.NET 5 (vNext)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx

In the new ASP.NET 5 (vNext) The call to get the current method name seems to have been removed.

The code below shows the call i was hoping to make:

```cs
string methodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

However the call to `GetCurrentMethod()` will cause a compiler error.

`CS0117 'MethodBase' does not contain a definition for 'GetCurrentMethod'`

I am using DNX Core 5.0.

I have checked the GitHub issues for .NET Core [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues) but have found no mention of the method.

Has this been removed on purpose?

What should i use instead?

Comment: Don't have have any vNext version installed. But from the [sources](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/mscorlib/src/System/Reflection/MethodBase.cs) it looks it should be there.

Comment: @Christian.K It seems that it is there for DNX Core 4.6 but is not there for DNX Core 5.0, as to why i'm not sure yet. Im not sure how they map as the method in question is not present in [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Reflection/ref/System.Reflection.cs) but is present in [coreclr](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/4cf8a6b082d9bb1789facd996d8265d3908757b2/src/mscorlib/src/System/Reflection/MethodBase.cs)